# What are "healthy exits" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not an expert in investment. Can anybody explain it to me please?

Analysts have expressed concern that Indian startups — many of which have raised hundreds of millions of dollars from private markets at extremely high valuations — need to start showing consistent profits and **healthy exits** for investors.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2021/07/16/tech/paytm-ipo-intl-hnk/index.html

Answer (score 3):

[Healthy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/healthy) exits on the investing world means that the company has generated a lot more money via an "[exit event](https://soject.com/startup-exit-strategy/)" than what was invested in them, so the investors can make a considerable profit. On the link above there are several "exit strategies" listed (going public, being acquired, and so on) and "healthy" is meant in its "considerable" meaning (4b on the linked definition above.)